# query column of string type with the date restrain in sqlserver.txt

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a sql table whose create sql is shown as following:

++++++++++ Create table script ++++++++

```
USE [TestDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [LogTime] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [EventTime] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [value] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

//+++++++++ End ++++++++

However when I select the data from the table,this is the value.

```
LogTime                         EventTime            value
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2010-11-26 12:10:31.907000000   634263264000000000   1.145604E-10
2010-11-26 12:10:31.907000000   634263264000000000   1.373898E-9
2010-11-26 12:10:31.907000000   634263264000000000   -2.3787419E-10
```

Why the Eventtime is not the date format?

Also,I need to select something from the table according a date period,for example get dat whose eventtime between "2010-10-12 12:00:00" and "2010-10-12 17:00:00",so how to build the sql words?

BWT,I can not change the structure of the table,and I just need to read data from the db,never write.

**

> UPDATE:

**

One of the sql date format is :

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.MMM(24h)    ODBC Canonical (with milliseconds)  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE(), 121)     1972-02-19 06:35:24.489
```

But why the milliseconds digit of date in my table is nine?

Like:

1972-02-19 06:35:24.**489**

my data: 2010-11-26 12:10:31.**907000000**

I want to remove the milliseconds,so how to convert it in the sql word?

Comment: Can you post the code that is used to populate the `Test` table?

Comment: What *is* `eventtime` - seconds, milliseconds?

Comment: I do not own the codes,the data is populated by other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the current values that you have shown for `EventTime`, i think you need to clarify from whoever is responsible for populating this table (as you have indicated that it is not your code) what format is the data in `EventTime` column.

As it currently is, i am not aware of any particular SQL date time format that can represent this information as a date for you to be able to do the processing of the WHERE condition that you want.

[List of common SQL Date formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Additionally, i would suggest that if possible, post the code that is responsible for populating the `Test`table as that might give some indicator as to the data (and its format) in `EventTime` column.

**Edit**: Based on the comments, it seems that the data is stored as a proper date (albeit in string format) in the database. If that is the case, the below should work.

Note: 121 is the format that includes milliseconds as well. You can optionally use 120 as well if your dates do not need milliseconds

```
SELECT LogTime, CONVERT(DateTime, eventTime, 121), value 
FROM Test
WHERE CONVERT(DateTime, eventTime, 121) BETWEEN 
    CONVERT(DateTime, '2010-10-12 12:00:00', 121) AND 
    CONVERT(DateTime, '2010-10-12 17:00:00', 121)
```

Note : You could potentially avoid the convert for each row on the 2 hardcoded values (possibly params) by doing it just once and storing it in a datetime variable instead.
Also, as per the [definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx), BETWEEN is inclusive of both boundaries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not own the codes,the data is populated by other people. But when I view the data by sql server 2005,the data of eventTime column in the table is something like "2010-12-12 22:00:00"

Comment: @hgUser - can you post the SELECT statement you are using to retrieve the data - and even the application code - if any that is used to execute the select statement. It seems from your comment that the Data is stored correctly in the DB - then it may be something related to how you are retrieving it

Comment: I just using "select LogTime,eventTime,value from Test"

Comment: @hguser - can you try doing a `SELECT LogTime, CONVERT(DateTime, eventTime, 121), value from Test' instead and see if that gets you the date correctly? I still think that if the date is stored correctly in the db as per your comment, you can use CONVERT and a BETWEEN clause and it should work...

Comment: Thanks for your attention,I will have a try tomorrow,since I am at home right now. :)

Comment: Hi,InSane,I have do the test and `SELECT LogTime, CONVERT(DateTime, eventTime, 121)' will cause a conversion error,but 'select convert(datetime2,logtime) from Test' work.

Answer (score 0):

if you can, change eventTime to the datetime data type instead of varchar

Comment: :( I can not change the table structure.